# PhoneGap/Cordova: Shake Event detection not smooth

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to detect shake event with PhoneGap API, but I find program execution is not smooth.

When we invoke watchAcceleration function, we set a parameter which represent monitor frequency like: options.frequency = 800;

Here is my question: With parameter "options.frequency = 800", device will only monitor Accelerometer every 0.8 second, but user may completed his shake gesture within 0.7 second, so we can't detect user's shake.

You may say just make the frequency parameter smaller. But I am worried that will cause performance loss(Need somebody confirm).

Then from some [article](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494783/Handling%20Shake%20Events), I found there is a parameter "acc.is_updating", I found it's always "undefined".

Do somebody know how to make user experience of shake more smoothly? Or is there any good plugin to detect shake gesture?

Comment: The only shake detection plugin for Cordova seems to be [cordova-plugin-shake-detection](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you found something. For future reference, there's a **shake.js** plugin mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809974/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-cordova-android), but I use [this fork of it](https://gist.github.com/ucavus/5418463).

Comment: Alex Gibson's shake.js plugin is not a Cordova plugin (it doesn't have plugin.xml and doesn't use navigator.accelerometer but rather [devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/devicemotion) for (mobile) web browsers). Also, the fork you've linked to is an old fork of Lee Crossley's [cordova-plugin-shake-detection](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection) and in the meantime Less has [addressed all the issues raised by the fork](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection/issues/14#issuecomment-93941789).