# How to detect shake event with cordova android?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to detect shaking event using Cordova 2.2.0 for android devices.
I found some question related to this topic but t's in native code for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398125/phonegap-cordova-shake-event-detect) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271448/how-to-detect-shake-event-with-android).

Does anyone knows how to detect this event using phonegap Cordova ? or I should write a plugin ?

Comment: i use a small frequency and compare current x,y and z values with the previous ones.. I don't know if there's a better solution

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it's not working in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [shake.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/). Ive been looking into it, but not implemented it. It looks promising.

Comment: @Walf - that fork is not a fork of Alex Gibson's shake.js. It's a fork of Lee Crossley's [cordova-plugin-shake-detection](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection). Also, Lee has address [all the fixes proposed by the fork](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection/issues/14).

Comment: Alex Gibson's shake.js is not a Cordova Plugin. It's a JavaScript plugin for (mobile web) browsers, using the [devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/devicemotion) API, while Cordova exposes a [`navigator.accelerometer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html) API. The two are not aligned, and that's been an [issue with the Cordova plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6069) since Feb 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Use the accelerometer to store the previous values (x, y and z). Defining the thresholds (x,y,z) you can detect shaking if the different betwen the previosValues and the actual once (event.value[i] where i=x,y ans z) is higher than the thresholds.

You also can use the magnitude of the acceleration values (Acc=sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)) or the timestamp  to obtain better results.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova offers the device-motion plugin, which (surprisingly) exposes a [`navigator.accelerometer`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html) object, [instead of aligning](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6069) with the W3C [deviceorientation/devicemotion](http://www.w3.org/TR/orientation-event/) standard published since 2011.

When the device lays flat on a surface, the (x, y, z) acceleration will be (0, 0, 9.81). The basic idea for detecting a shake is to watch the acceleration with a given frequency, calculate the delta from the previous sample, and decide if it's larger than a threshold.

```js
navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 300 });

// Assess the current acceleration parameters to determine a shake
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
  var accelerationChange = {};
  if (previousAcceleration.x !== null) {
    accelerationChange.x = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.x - acceleration.x);
    accelerationChange.y = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.y - acceleration.y);
    accelerationChange.z = Math.abs(previousAcceleration.z - acceleration.z);
  }

  previousAcceleration = {
    x: acceleration.x,
    y: acceleration.y,
    z: acceleration.z
  };

  if (accelerationChange.x + accelerationChange.y + accelerationChange.z > sensitivity) {
    // Shake detected, invoke callback
  }

}
```

A plugin doing that is Lee Crossley's [cordova-plugin-shake-detection](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake-detection).

Comment: Have you been able to get the plugin to work? I'm having problems with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907147/ionic-angular-hybrid-app-issue-with-getting-a-shake-event-working