# Ionic / Angular hybrid app, issue with getting a shake event working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is for a Ionic/Angular hybrid app. I'm trying get a `shake event` to fire using [cordova-plugin-shake](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake). It's supposed to reload a random image. So far a random image is showing up on load, but it's not working when testing a `shake event` in the simulator.

I'm getting the error `ReferenceError: shake is not defined` However the docs say `You do not need to reference any JavaScript, the Cordova plugin architecture will add a shake object to your root automatically when you build.` What am I missing here? How can I get this to work? I'm using cordova ver 6.3.0.

Here's app.js

```
angular.module('TarotApp', ['ionic','ngAnimate'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    shake.startWatch(onShake, 40);
  });
})

angular.module('TarotApp')
    .controller('TarotCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.tarotImg = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

        $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];


});

var onShake = function () {
  $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];
};
```

Here's index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="TarotApp">

    <ion-pane>

     <!--  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">

      </ion-header-bar>-->

      <ion-content ng-controller="TarotCtrl">


            <img ng-src="img/{{randTarotImg}}.jpg" class="tarot"/> 


      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried to implement this function inside a controller?

Comment: @Anokrize Thank you. I tried it, not working. Still getting `shake is not defined` error and I'm not getting a random image when testing the `shake` in the simulator.

Comment: Have you added the plugin ? `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-shake` If yes, you can try to remove the platform and readd it

Comment: Thanks, yes added. I'll try it. I do see that it's in the cordova_plugins.js file in `platforms/ios/www`, it's linking to the correct file. The entry reads as follows: `{
        "id": "cordova-plugin-shake.Shake",
        "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-shake/www/shake.js",
        "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-shake",
        "clobbers": [
            "shake"
        ]
    },`

Super frustrating. The github site says `You do not need to reference any JavaScript, the Cordova plugin architecture will add a shake object to your root automatically when you build.` But I can't access it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shake object only gets added when you build and deploy to a real phone. Not if you're testing in the browser. Add this to avoid the error when testing

```
if(window.shake) shake.startWatch(onShake,40);
```

Comment: Ah I wondered that, I tested it on a iPhone6 and didn't get it to work.

Comment: I used an android phone, Samsung Galaxy S5